# Call an event handler function Python3

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, callback, event-handling

I need to call an event handler function to retrieve a variables stored inside of it.

This is a part of my code:

```
def handler(event):
    current = combobox.current()
    if current !=1:
        for label in labels.values():
            label.config(relief='flat')
        value = res[current]
        print('\n',value)
        label = labels[value]
        label.config(relief='raised')
        
        handler_type=protocols[value].type
        handler_adress=protocols[value].adress
#        print(handler_type)
#        print(handler_adress)
        return (handler_adress, handler_type)

even_fun=handler()
print(even_fun.handler_adress)
print(even_fun.handler_type)
```

in this case I get this error:

```
    even_fun=handler()

TypeError: handler() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'
```

if I add the parameter event : `even_fun=handler(event)` i get this error:

```
    even_fun=handler(event)

NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

Comment: Please [edit] your code to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You could set the default parameter of the value if you don't need it(I think you are using command in the tkinter):

```
def handler(event=None):
```